# How to load the css to my react project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and I have a problem.

I have a code like this

```
<body>

    <link href="css/rev_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
<!--    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->
    <script src="lib/react.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/react.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/react-dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/react-dom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root">
        <!-- This div's content will be managed by React. -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/babel">

      var Counter = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function () {
          return { count: 0 };
        },
        handleClick: function () {
          this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1,
          });
        },
        render: function () {
          return (
            <div class="header">
    <label class="web_name">Revegator</label>
    <input class="search_bar" type="search" placeholder="Search here"/>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="container-4">
            <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search here" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu_items_div">

        <a class="menu_items">Home</a>
        <a class="menu_items">Profile</a>
        <img class="menu_items" src="img/bell.png" alt=""/>
        <img class="menu_items" src="img/drop.png" alt=""/>
    </div>

</div>
          );
        }
      });
      ReactDOM.render(
        <Counter />,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    </script>
</body>
```

But the css has not been applied here. How can I load my css file properly? I have been using AngularJS upto now. In angular I could just simply load the css like this

```
<link href="css/rev_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

How can I do this in react?

Comment: If you put your link tag into head tag, does it work? Maybe you are not using html5 cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the **TOP** of your html ( even before `<html>` tag ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then put, `<link >` tag inside `<head>` .

```
< head>

   <!-- -->
  <link href="css/rev_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
```

If it does not work, it means you are using wrong path , so , check in the console if  `css/rev_css.css` is not found .

Comment: ^ what he said. You should be loading scripts and CSS files in the <head> section, not the <body>